# iOS 7, iPhone, Proximity Sensor

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, proximitysensor

This is a short question but it was bugging me for a whole night. I have few of my own applications here (I write Objective-C Only and I use ARC) where if I write in appDelegate - application didFinishLaunching...:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(proximityStateChanged:) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

I get perfectly normal response. Display turns off, I get notification with changed proximityState, etc.

Now, I have application that is not mine and I should modify it (I have Xcode project - source files). I only should implement some changes based on proximitySensor. I am absolutely unable to enable proximityMonitoring? I am doing the same thing as in other applications but it is simply not calling the notification and not changing proximityState. Biggest difference is that this application's appDelegate is .mm - mixed language, but I really don't think this should be a problem.

Is there some GLOBAL way to disable sensors or only proximity sensor? Can some service for recording audio or playing audio be able to disable proximity sensor? Any clue would be golden! I really don't understand what could be preventing me from enabling this feature.
Cheers everyone.

Comment: Not all iOS devices have proximity sensors. To determine if proximity monitoring is available, attempt to enable it. If the value of the proximityMonitoringEnabled property remains NO, proximity monitoring is not available.

Comment: If it is not the device's problem, did you make sure nobody has changed proximityMonitoringEnabled property except you?

Comment: Searched through the whole code, only I am mentioning proximity. I am testing on my device (iPhone 5) which has proximity sensor and it's working on another project where I wrote the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FUU!

ProximitySensor is being disabled if the application doesn't support Portrait orientation! You can do whatever you want, but if Portrait is not checked as a Device Orientation, ProximitySensor wont start up!

Comment: You should accept your own answer, it is encouraged on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. When you say you "have an application that is not mine", do yo have the source code, or are you looking to patch it somehow?

If you have the full source code you should be able to insert the same calls you show above and have them work. You would need to turn on proximity monitoring, add an observer, and then add your observer method to the class that you've added as an observer.

I don't think you have to set a flag in the info.plist file in order to enable proximity monitoring, but I'm not positive. I've only ever used it as an experiment, and that was a while ago.

Comment: Yes, I have source code, and sure I am calling above mentioned methods in the AppDelegate.mm of that application. What kind of flag would that be if it is required?