# Which iOS devices have proximity monitoring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, proximitysensor

I'd like to know which iOS devices have a proximity sensor. Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test in code to determine whether a device supports proximity monitoring:

[iOS 7, iPhone, Proximity Sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895320/ios-7-iphone-proximity-sensor)

And here is a hardware list:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Features

So basically, all iPhones and nothing else :)